# Timeline object type for GarageBand-type UI?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

I'm working on a timeline app that needs to have a Garageband-type interface. I'm not a new developer, and I have a background in CGI and have been a Mac dev for over 20 years, but I'm a little stuck on what **kind** of objects to make that would represent the objects in the timeline. Are they UIViews? Drawn with QuartzCore? I Googled the heck out of the concept and looked at some books and came up empty. Any ideas on how to make these objects? I'd rather ask then start in one direction and realize there could be a better way down the road. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that they allow user interaction, they're probably implemented as custom `UIView` subclasses. Since views are layer-backed, and since the timeline isn't flying all over the place and doing crazy complex animations, there's not really a good reason to have the UI be built directly from layers.